# Windows update error 0x80070643 (KB4041994)

Tags: windows

I try to update my windows but I got this message:

[image]

I tried to reboot service but it didn't work.
Current version of my laptop: Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.192)
I am afraid this will be affected to future releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Microsoft forum article suggests that it is a Windows Update glitch:

[Update for Windows 10 Version 1709 for x64-based Systems (KB4041994) — error 0x80070643](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/update-for-windows-10-version-1709-for-x64-based/c34ff749-cb9c-42d2-85da-169e5d6c54d4).

The article further suggests that the OP there has the later build of Windows, and that the problem may be suppressed by hiding the update (how-to provided in the linked article).

Comment: So it won't affect future release?

Comment: Not sure to be honest, but the article indicated 38 people helped by the reply, so it may be a good indicator.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar problem on my PC and my laptop. My error code was as follows:

2018-08 Update for Windows 10 Version 1709 for x64-based Systems (KB4023057) - Error 0x80070643

After much kafuffle and reading quite a few articles and Microsoft waffle pages I decided to do it my own "straightforward" way. This is my story, if it helps you I am content. Summary:

```
Close/save all open applications;
Run Windows Update TroubleShooter;
Find the latest Cumulative Update;
Run the Cumulative Update;
Allow the computer to do the necessary restart processing.
```

The description below is what I did. It worked both times for me; firstly on my PC and secondly on my laptop. The difference with my laptop was that I didn't repeat the download of the Cumulative Update as I had already done this for the PC, I just ported the Update to the laptop via USB; everything else was the same.
On the laptop the whole process took about 40 minutes, start to finish. I didn't time it on my PC as I was doing things in slow stages. The download of the update is quite large (900Mb) so watch out for download charges if your ISP makes you pay for such things.

All descriptions/statements below apply solely to me. I am describing what I did and what I think. Like with Microsoft and others, any decision by you to follow any aspect of my description is entirely at your own risk. For any "lawyers" out there, any reference to "you" or implications that I am telling you what to do is just an unintended flaw in my poor English grammar.

1. Save and close all the applications that are being used:

The Cumulative Update will requires a restart of the computer so, for me, it was best to save any data now and close all the applications I had open in an orderly manner.

2. Find and run the Windows Update TroubleShooter:

Search the web for "Windows Update TroubleShooter". The page I ended up on was this:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter

Click the appropriate download link on this page. I am running Windows 10 (Version 1709; x64) so, for me it was: "Download Troubleshooter for Windows 10"; it was a small file, around 200Kb.
The download file was "wu170509.diagcab". I always "Save > Virus check > and then run".

Run the Troubleshooter (I double-clicked it);
On its first page, click "Advanced", then ensure "Apply repairs automatically" is checked, and finally click "Run as administrator". It reloads itself, click "Next" and let it run.

Whenever it found a problem I chose the "Apply this fix" option.
When it reports that it has completed, close the TroubleShooter.
This took me about 10 minutes to do (I am slow and I was also trying to make a cup of tea!).

3. Find the computer's details:

Load the Settings page; right-click the Windows "Start" icon -> Settings -> System -> About.
Note the following:

```
Under Device Specifications, note the System Type (mine is 64 bit "x64")
Under Windows Specifications, note the Edition, Version and OS Build details.
```

4. Find and run the Microsoft Update Catalogue:

Open a browser (mine is Internet Explorer) in Admin mode ("Run as Administrator" from its icon's Context Menu - I don't know why you have to do this but you get an error otherwise on IE);
Search the web for "Microsoft Update Catalogue"; the page I ended up on was this:
https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/home.aspx

Search for the latest Cumulative update for your version. I entered the following search terms that relate to my system in this year "2018 cumulative update windows 10 1709 x64";
Top of my returned list (the latest cumulative update) was:

2018-09 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1709 for x64-based Systems (KB4464217)

Note its KB number and click on its Title.
An "Update Details" window opens; click on the "More Information" link and a web page opens, mine was:

September 17, 2018—KB4464217 (OS Build 16299.666)

Verify the KB number with the Microsoft Catalog number just to make sure.

I only proceeded with this Update because its Build Number was greater than my current one (from section 3 above); for me, going backwards sounds like a route to a bigger mess.

Once I was content I was going forward I went back to the Microsoft Catalog (closing web pages and windows as necessary) and clicked the "Download" link for this Cumulative Update (KB4464217); a "Download" window appears. Click the link to download it (it says 863Mb). My download took 5 minutes via an Ethernet connection (no idea on timing regarding a WiFi download).

5. Run and check the Cumulative Update:

When the download had completed (and after virus checking it), I opened its folder and double-clicked the file therein and let it run. It took about 30 minutes to do its work. Once started it needed no help from me so I wandered off and did other work.

Once the Cumulative Update had completed I let it do its necessary restart. This is in fact a couple of restarts and took about another 10 minutes to complete.

Once these restarts had completed I loaded my system and did an immediate Windows Update. It returned with no errors and reported that my system was up to date - Yippee!

Notes:

A. There was one difference between updating my PC and laptop. On the PC my Desktop layout was undisturbed, on my laptop the Desktop layout was reset. I have no idea why the difference occurred.

B. In the middle of writing this, when I got to describing the Windows Update TroubleShooter, I decided to rerun the TroubleShooter on my PC. To my surprise it reported errors. I had done nothing of any significance since applying the Cumulative Update and checking it, just some simple Powershell stuff (Microsoft product) and a bit of internet browsing like news and football results (via Internet Explorer, another Microsoft product). It seems to me that Microsoft are screwing up their own Update System! What clever people they are - not.

Good Luck peoples - Pay It Forward.

Comment: Just ran a search of the Microsoft Update Catalog on the error KB - KB4023057. It returned zero results. Aren't Microsoft wonderful! :)